# How do you manipulate the list, and place restrictions? like restricting changes dependent on a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am currently trying to build a game of othello using only lists, and currently, I am in a bind, for creating a multiplayer setup. I am trying to control the turns but I don't know how. I am unable to get the lists to change as the players' input values.

```
import copy


def new_board():
    row1=[[1],[0]*8]
    row2=[[2],[0]*8]
    row3=[[3],[0]*8]
    row4=[[4],[0]*8]
    row5=[[5],[0]*8]
    row6=[[6],[0]*8]
    row7=[[7],[0]*8]
    row8=[[8],[0]*8]
    rowR=[[0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]


    row4[1][3] = 1
    row4[1][4] = 2
    row5[1][3] = 2
    row5[1][4] = 1


    print(row1)
    print(row2)
    print(row3)
    print(row4)
    print(row5)
    print(row6)
    print(row7)
    print(row8)
    print(rowR)



usr_start= input("wanna play reversi? y/n= ")
usr_start.lower()
if usr_start == 'y':
    usr_plyrcnt =int(input("how many players? 1 or 2"))
    new_board()
    if usr_plyrcnt==2:
        player1= int(input("input coordinates for change"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're not using your

```
player1= int(input("input coordinates for change"))
```

?

Comment: hi, i am sorry i meant, i am unsure how to approach this. I completely realise that that area is incomplete.